# extracting version string in shell script

Tags: linux, shell

I've a progam installed in my linux box called my-scheduler-1.1.0-1112

When I do rpm -qa | grep my, it lists as shown below:

```
my-scheduler-1.1.0-1112
```

I want a command which will extract 1.1.0-1112 which is version part in my shell script.

what would be the command to extract it in shell script?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not sure what other version strings you may encounter, but you can try:

```
sed -e 's/^[^0-9]*-//g'
```

---

This is a `sed` replace. It's matching the regular expression `^[^0-9]*-`, which is:

- starting from the beginning of the String
- match as many non-numbers as there are
- then the very next character is a `-`

And it replaces everything that matched with a blank, essentially removing it. This should leave everything after that which is the version string.

Comment: This seems to be working...Can you explain what it does & how it extracts version?

Comment: Why is - needed? Can I just use sed -e 's/^[^0-9]*//g'  I simply want all the characters after "my-scheduler-"

Comment: @Mike I guess it's not needed, I had it in there when I was trying a different regex. As for -e: http://unixhelp.ed.ac.uk/CGI/man-cgi?sed

Answer (score 3):

For this question you can try the **--queryformat** parameter for rpm.

like:

```
rpm -qa --queryformat '%{NAME}' | grep my
```

should print

```
my-scheduler
```

without the version string... What is much better as mugling it with sed or like. Because you can get something like `package-1.0.3-rc2` or soo..

For version-release: use:

```
--queryformat "%{VERSION}-%{RELEASE}"
```

and maybe will be useful read http://www.rpm.org/max-rpm/ch-queryformat-tags.html - here is many useful query format tags, so you can directly can get what you want and in what format you want, without scripting...

Comment: I don't want name...I want the version part which is 1.1.0-1112